# elasticsearch bulk API using pandas

Tags: pandas, elasticsearch

I have a dataframe that I can import in elasticsearch without any problem. But each row will be created as a new record. I want to save the destination number as ID and update the document with additional records.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

u_cols = ["destination", "status", "batchid", "dateint", "message", "senddate"]

audit_trail = StringIO('''
918968400000 |  DELIVRD  | abcd_xyz-e89a4ebd3729675c | 20150226103700 | "some company is advertising here" | 2015-04-02 13:12:18  
918968400000 |  DELIVRD  | efgh_xyz-e89a4ebd3729675c | 20160226103700 | "some company is advertising here" | 2016-04-02 13:12:18  
8918968400000 |  FAILED  | abcd_xyz-e89a4ebd3729675c | 20150826103700 | "some company is advertising here" | 2015-08-02 13:12:18  
8918968400000 |  DELIVRD  | xyz_abc-e89a4ebd3729675c | 20140226103700 | "some company is advertising here" | 2014-04-02 13:12:18  
918968400000 |  FAILED  | abcd_pqr-e89a4ebd3729675c | 20150221103700 | "some company is advertising here" | 2015-04-21 13:12:18  
''')

df11 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep="|", names = u_cols  )


import json
tmp = df11.to_json(orient = "records")
df_json= json.loads(tmp)


mylist=[]
for doc in df_json:
    action = { "_index": "myindex3", "_type": "myindex1type", "_source": doc }
    mylist.append(action)


import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://23.23.186.196:9200')
helpers.bulk(es, mylist)
```

In the above case I expect only 2 documents. One document ID 918968400000 with 3 records and the other 8918968400000 with only 2 records. These records will be nested something like this...

```
doc={"campaigns" : [{"status": "FAILED", "batchid": "abcd_xyz-e89a4ebd3729675c", "dateint": 20150826103700, "message" : "some company is advertising here", "senddate": "2015-08-02 13:12:18"},
{"status": "DELIVRD", "batchid": "xyz_abc-e89a4ebd3729675c", "dateint": 20140226103700, "message" : "some company is advertising here", "senddate": "2014-04-02 13:12:18" }]}

res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=8918968400000, body=doc)
```

I need the pandas dataframe to use bulk API to insert the data as shown above. Is it possible?

---

Update

I changed the option type from index to update. This stores all the fields those I need. But it does not store them as nested objects.

```
mylist=[]
for id, doc in enumerate(df_json):
    mydoc[id] = {}
    mydoc[id]['doc']=doc
    mydoc[id]['doc_as_upsert'] = True
    action = { "_index": "myindex9", "_type": "myindex1type", "_id": doc['destination'] , "_on_type": "update", "_source": mydoc }
    mylist.append(action)
```

Is there any way to store rows as nested objects?